# EXC_BREAKPOINT due to a wrong conversion

Tags: ios, swift, exception

While checking the issues reported by Crashlytics, it seems that I have a EXC_BREAKPOINT error for the following line:

```
self.caloriesFor100 = Int((cartFood.nbCalories.floatValue / 100) * cartFood.quantite.floatValue)
```

- caloriesFor100 is a `Int`.
- cartFood.nbCalories is an `NSNumber` which is supposed to have float values.
- cartFood.quantite is also an `NSNumber` which is supposed to have float values.

I did not succeed to reproduce the issue. What could possibly cause an EXC_BREAKPOINT in this code?

Full stack trace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  LSDP                           0x10269ccbc specialized CartFoodModelinit(_:) (CartFoodModel.swift:88)
1  LSDP                           0x10268a570 specialized CartFoodCell.cartFoodObjc (CartFoodModel.swift)
2  LSDP                           0x102689600 @objc CartFoodCell.cartFoodObjc (<compiler-generated>)
3  LSDP                           0x102664c7c -[PanierDuJourViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (PanierDuJourViewController.m:156)
4  UIKit                          0x18bf10148 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 668
5  UIKit                          0x18bf0fe00 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80
6  UIKit                          0x18bf0eb1c -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2280
7  UIKit                          0x18bf0a668 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 140
8  UIKit                          0x18be47770 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1420
9  QuartzCore                     0x1863e925c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
10 QuartzCore                     0x1863ed3ec CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 324
11 QuartzCore                     0x186359aa0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 320
12 QuartzCore                     0x1863815d0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 580
13 UIKit                          0x18c22054c _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 172
14 UIKit                          0x18c7fd4c0 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5520
15 UIKit                          0x18c7f6258 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152
16 CoreFoundation                 0x18221b404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
17 CoreFoundation                 0x18221ac2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
18 CoreFoundation                 0x18221879c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
19 CoreFoundation                 0x182138da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
20 GraphicsServices               0x18411b020 GSEventRunModal + 100
21 UIKit                          0x18c11978c UIApplicationMain + 236
22 LSDP                           0x1025fce28 main (main.m:16)
23 libdyld.dylib                  0x181bc9fc0 start + 4
```

Comment: What's the full error message? (show it in your question, not in a comment)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just added the stack trace

Comment: That's not the error message I'm referring to. There should be a plain (sort of) English error message shown in the crash log.

Comment: I did not reproduce the issue on my local environment, I only have the logs provided by Crashlytics

Comment: Is it possible that your `cartFood` instance has been deallocated when the exception  happens?

Comment: Check nbCalories, quantite can be nil.Are these objectcivec data objects?

Answer (score 0):

You may catch this exception in case if `NSNumber` property will be `nil`. So maybe it is better to change `nbCalories` to has an option value.

Comment: If the `NSNumber` property could be `nil` then that means it would need to be an optional. If the property were optional, the code, as posted, wouldn't compile.

Comment: @rmaddy I told about situation when `NSNumber` couldn't be nil, but it is. Unexpectedly found nil error could happens (e.g. cartFood's class defined in Objective-C and property not marked as nullable).

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem and its solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54139111/1987726).
Since your app crashes at `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, it might be that the cell should display an entry of your table (`CartFoodCell.cartFoodObjc`) that no longer exists.
But without more code, this is just a guess. Please double check it in your code.